Is there a way to reserve bandwidth for ssh on linux / debian?
I ssh into my dev machine, and then start a download, for instance "ollama pull llama3"
This uses all of the available bandwidth for the network interface, which makes ssh unresponsive until the download completes.
Is there a way to reserve some amount of bandwidth for ssh?
I've tried the "trickle" utility, e.g. "trickle -s -d 200 ollama pull llama3", but that did not have any effect.

That doesn't sound right at all. What kind of connection is in use – Wifi? ADSL? Does the SSH session become completely unresponsive or only mostly?

1 Gigabit Ethernet, then fiber. "Mostly unresponsive" would cover it, there are no progress updates from the download, but can get a ctrl-c trough.

I totally don't know ollama pull. Does it pass the job to some background downloader and return immediately? If not, i.e. if it downloads in the foreground, then it's normal you cannot interact with the parent shell until the download completes and the foreground child process exits.

It runs in the foreground and prints download status output, but it might hand of the download to a background process.
But that's a bit beside the point, other ssh sessions to the same machine are affected as well.

Look up traffic shaping. Under linux TrafficControl (tc) (and iptables) will allow you to do this, there are plenty examples on the interwebs to help you.

Yeah, I would say that's definitely not normal for Ethernet – does it also happen when you download anything else (or run an iperf3 test), or is it specifically just Ollama?

It is normal for unconfigured ethernet to behave like this. The download just gobbles up all available bandwith. However, by default SSH traffic will already have the ToS bit set and given priority. This doesnt seem to be the case in the users configuration.
